# Set abolute position canvas matplotlib in PySide window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

I have here this situation:

```
btn_1 = QtGui.QPushButton("1", self)
btn_1.move(0, 20)

btn_2 = QtGui.QPushButton("3", self)
btn_2.move(100, 20)

btn_3 = QtGui.QPushButton("3", self)
btn_3.move(200, 20)

fig = pyplot.figure()
#---plot things---#
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
self.setCentralWidget(canvas) #here is the problem
```

I get a canvas from matplotlib and set it in my PySide window, but when I do it, the widget canvas is generated above the buttons. I'd like to set the position of the canvas.

self is a object of this class:

```
class myForm(QtGui.QMainWindow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use layout classes like `QHBoxLayout()` and `QVBoxLayout` but I think your class must inherit `QWidget` (look [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/layoutmanagement/) for examples of how to use layout classes). If you want to use `QMainWindow` (which has its own layout) you have to put your buttons/actions in a `QToolBar`, `QDockBar` or `QMenuBar`. See in the 
[docs](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMainWindow.html?highlight=setcentralwidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget) the layout of `QMainWindow`.

Comment: I changed to QWidget and worked these layouts. And I put this too: `canvas.setParent(self)`